# What MySQL query can return a result set that meets all criteria for example return all photos that have these 'x' keywords?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

**photos:  id, name**

**keywords: id, keyword**

**photo_keyword relationship table: photo_id, keyword_id**

In other words one photo may be associated to multiple keywords describing the photo

```
photos:
id | name
1  | photo 1
2  | photo 2
3  | photo 3

keywords:
id | keyword
1  | NHL
2  | Toronto
3  | Montreal
4  | Boston
5  | Chicago
6  | Canadiens
7  | Leafs


photo_keyword:
photo_id | keyword_id
1 | 2
1 | 7
1 | 1
2 | 1
2 | 3
2 | 6
3 | 2
3 | 7
```

I would like to write/build a query dynamically where i can get a list of photos that meet all criteria asked for.

example:  I want all photos that have Toronto (2) and Leafs (7) as keywords

ie) I want to retrieve photo 1 and  photo 3 as they are the two that have both keywords

if I asked for photos that have NHL (1) Toronto (2) and Leafs (7) as criteria, only photo 1 would be returned.

The obvious first attempt involved joining the tables:

```
SELECT photo.id, photo.name
FROM photo
LEFT JOIN photo_keyword ON photo_keyword.photo_id = photo.id
LEFT JOIN keyword ON keyword.id = photo_keyword.keyword_id
WHERE keyword.keyword = 'Toronto'
```

returns photos 1 and 2

This type of query can be used whenever i am searching for all photos meeting 1 keyword criteria. However,
trying to get photos that meet the criteria of two keywords is a different story.

I tried

```
 WHERE keyword.keyword IN ('NHL, 'Toronto', 'Leafs')
```

but that returns photos that meet either criteria but no necessarily both. In this case photo 1 and 2 as well.

So how do I build a query that only returns only the photos that meets all keyword criteria?

Any help on this would be immensely appreciated!

**Update:**

With everyone's comments this is what I put together and seems to do what I require:

```
SELECT
    photos.id
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN photo_keyword pk ON pk.photo_id = photos.id
LEFT JOIN keywords kw ON kw.id = pk.keyword_id
WHERE kw.keyword IN ('NHL', 'Toronto', 'Leafs')
GROUP BY photos.id
HAVING COUNT(kw.keyword) = 3;
```

Comment: @nandhu,@user1174754 can i know what type of output u r expecting........... pls tell with example(with keyword and expected output)

Comment: The standard solution: 'WHERE x IN ('a','b','c') GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3'

Comment: Strawberry - yes i see that now and will post the revised query in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you know keywords cannot be repeated for a given photo, I think you could accomplish this with something like:

```
SELECT photo.name from photo where photo.id IN (
SELECT photo.id
FROM photo
LEFT JOIN photo_keyword ON photo_keyword.photo_id = photo.id
LEFT JOIN keyword ON keyword.id = photo_keyword.keyword_id
WHERE keyword.keyword IN ('NHL, 'Toronto', 'Leafs')
GROUP BY (photo.id)
HAVING COUNT (photo.name) = *Number of passed keywords*)
```

Could also do this with UNIONS, etc. but a lot of this depends on what you know about your keywords and how you are getting them.

Comment: matthew - thank you for this.  your solution and Strawberry's comment made me dig a little further. I will edit my response above with a hybrid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT p.id, p.name FROM photo_keyword pk
  JOIN keywords k
    ON k.id = pk.keyword_id
   JOIN photos p
     ON p.id = pk.photo_id
GROUP BY
  pk.photo_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(IF(k.keyword = 'Toronto', 1, NULL)) > 0 AND
  COUNT(IF(k.keyword = 'Leafs', 1, NULL)) > 0
```

Comment: Devart - interesting approach and I did get a chance to test it. It would allow building the query dynamically iterating through the requested keywords and not having to add the number of keywords to the query.